# email alert in workflow rule

Tags: workflow

I could not find a suitable post for my requirement so apologies .

I have a custom object student with an email field. when user enters an email, I need to trigger a workflow which will send an email to student only and not to the record owner. so in workflow rule , I set criteria =Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria , rule criteria : student.Email contains .com.

In workflow, action=email alert, Recipient Type: Email Field, then under `setup -> Search 'deliverability' -> Under email deliverability, set Access level is 'All Email' is already checked.` still the student doesn't receive an email. Please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: check if your WF rule is active and firing.

Comment: check email logs to see if email sent and didn't bounce

Comment: workflow rule is active, No email logs

Comment: Can you check "Test Deliverability" of Org. Here is the link, https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_test_email_delivery.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I checked in Test Deliverability, whatever business email OR personal email I give it isn't going. so an issue with the IP addresses?In workflow, action=email, User=Current user, then he gets an email but not the student.

Comment: Just to be sure, the emails that you're testing this with do contain `.com`, correct? That aside, I think a better criteria would be `Student.Email not equal to <null>` where `<null>` means that you'd just leave the criteria value field blank. Otherwise, your workflow wouldn't fire if a student has a email domain that only contains .org, .edu, etc...

Comment: I believe your existing workflow rule would also not fire if you change the email field from `example1@domain.com` to `example2@domain.com`. That's because I believe the behavior of `and subsequently edited to meet criteria` is effectively `fire only when the record did not previously meet the criteria, but it now does`